# how to run end to end test in Protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am new to angularjs ,trying to test my app with karma,jasmine and protractor.
here is my conf.js:

```
exports.config = {

seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
capabilities: {
              'browserName': 'chrome'
              },
             specs: ['spec.js'],
            jasmineNodeOpts: {
            showColors: true,
            }
         };
```

here is my spec.js

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {

it('should have a title', function() {
    browser.get('http://localhost/First-angular-App/source/');
    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Firstangular app');
});
});
```

after running protractor conf.js I get this:

but can't run my test how can i do this??

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: C:\wamp\www\First-angular-App>protractor conf.js
WARNING - pattern spec.js did not match any files.
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
@MichaelRadionov  i get this :\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: Spec patterns did not match any files.

Comment: The error message tells exactly why your tests are not running. This option specifies a path to your specs `specs: ['spec.js']`. Is `spec.js` in the same directory with `conf.js`?

Comment: @MichaelRadionov i make separate folder for spec.js and conf.js is just insid my app folder both are not in same folder

Comment: Then modify `specs` option in `conf.js` and set a path to a folder with your specs relative to `conf.js`: `specs: ['tests/spec.js']` or even better `specs: ['tests/**/*.js']` (will take all files in *tests/* directory as test files)

Comment: @MichaelRadionov thanks

Answer (score 1):

As noted above:

> The error message tells exactly why your tests are not running. This option specifies a path to your specs: ['spec.js']. Modify conf.js and set a path to a folder with your specs relative to conf.js: specs: ['tests/spec.js'] or even better specs: ['tests/**/*.js'] (will take all files in tests/ directory as test files).

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading my node version to LTS([Node Website](https://nodejs.org/en/)), I fixed this problem.